# Delete row with certain text

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code that cleans up my data and sets text to columns. The row always starts with the word `Planning`. I need a code that will delete that row and the four rows above it. Hopefully this isn't a hard code.

Comment: Have you tried `find`?

Comment: No it isn't hard code, but SO is not a "do my code for me" website... The ultimate "How to ask a VBA question on SO":
1. Write down all the steps that you want your code to accomplish
2. Write out the pseudocode to accomplish your goal
3. Break out each of those steps and Google or search SO for the code related to that step
4. Replace the pseduocode with real code and test. Debug errors.
5. If there are errors you can't get around through searching or trial and error, THEN you can ask a new question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I'd wait for some code on your part, but this isn't too complex, so here's something that should get you started:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow&, i&
Dim findStr$

findStr = "Planning"

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1 ' change this to 2 if you have headers
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = findStr Then
        'Range(Rows(i), Rows(i - 4)).Select
        Range(Rows(i), Rows(i - 4)).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

This is assuming that "Planning" will be in Column A ("The row always starts with the word 'Planning'"). If not, change the ranges to match where it would be found.